# Password hashing compatible with Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, passwords

Is there a secure password hashing library (e.g. phpass) or hashing method that I can easily use in both PHP and Java?

Comment: MD5/SHA256 are both available in both Java and PHP natively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want do the easy thing, you can use sha-N with salt. (N being 1, 256 or 512)

---

Jeff Atwood did a nice blog post on that recently, saying that `bcrypt` and `PBKDF2` are the best options.

In PHP you can [use `bcrypt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) (and in [Java too)](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)

---

**Related topics:**

- [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

**Resouces:**

- [Coding Horror - Speed Hashing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html)
- [Security Stack exchange - Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage)

Answer (score 2):

Any standard library such as SHA*, MD* will do. SHA>2 is recommended (e.g. SHA512).

Answer (score 0):

[md5](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_md5.asp) and [SHA with salt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) are the most widely used ones.