# Bcrypt Java and Php don't match

Tags: java, php, bcrypt

I have a web application in php that makes register of a user and when a user puts password I put this code to Hash with Bcrypt

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

and I want to make the same thing in Java, and I put this

```
BCrypt.hashpw(passTxt.getText(),BCrypt.gensalt())
```

and the two password don't matches.
what can I do to the passwords matches?

Comment: You'd have to keep the same SALT between the languages. Notice you are generating one in Java, but not in PHP (and again, it would need to be identical).

Comment: and how can i put the same Salt? and how can I know what SALT i'm using?

Comment: **Try this** Its clearly defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079700/password-hashing-compatible-with-java-and-php)

Comment: @SandroMedeiros You could save the salt in a file and then read it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the same salt in PHP and JAVA in order to get the same result. They wont be exactly the same, but almost.

I wrote *almost*, because if you use the **password_hash()** function in PHP, then the prefix of the result will be different from the result generated by other techniquest. The hash generated by password_hash() will start with this prefix $2y$, however other methods will generate the exact same hash, but with the $2a$ prefix.

Here is a java code:

```
import org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(BCrypt.hashpw("applewood", "$2a$10$8lMtqu7E3veYGcm1bHId5u"));
    }    
}
```

Where the result is: **$2a$10$8lMtqu7E3veYGcm1bHId5u32B7MH48xPXqMVKlNSYX3rnnHyKvYQi**

Let's see it in PHP:

```
<?php
    print crypt("applewood", "$2a$10$8lMtqu7E3veYGcm1bHId5u") . "\n";
    print password_hash("applewood", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("salt" => "8lMtqu7E3veYGcm1bHId5u"));
```

The result will be the following:
**$2a$**10$8lMtqu7E3veYGcm1bHId5u32B7MH48xPXqMVKlNSYX3rnnHyKvYQi
**$2y$**10$8lMtqu7E3veYGcm1bHId5u32B7MH48xPXqMVKlNSYX3rnnHyKvYQi

[To learn more about the prefixes in the salt and the result hases in Bcrypt, read this article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)